# Error in calibration with known uncertainties (weighted regression)

Tags: regression, weighted-regression, calibration

Suppose we have an instrument that we want to calibrate. We measure $y_i$ at different values $x_i$ and fit a linear function $y=a+bx$ with *known* standard deviations $\sigma_i$ in $y_i$.

EDIT: It should be noted, that for the fitting, I used weighted least squares, thus minimising

$\sum(y_i-a-bx_i)/\sigma_i^2$.

For the calibration function however, we need the inverse relationship, i.e. $x=-(a/b)+(1/b)y$. What can we say about the uncertainty in $x$? If the uncertainty in $y_i$ was *not* known, we would have the standard deviation (see eg. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calibration_curve with $k=1$)

Answer (score -1):

Found an article answering my question: http://www.ltrr.arizona.edu/webhome/jburns/Articles%20-Read/masslav.pdf

Comment: Please summarize the main points in the article that answer your question. You can also click the check mark noting that your question has been answered.